# How to join table with tree table by one of the table specified where condition

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

A have two tables which I want to join table to get results, please look at this SQL working fine.

```
function getTotalCheque_per_day($date)
{
    $this->db->select_sum('(osp.`payment_amount`)', 'payment' );
    $this->db->from("ospos_sales_payments as osp");
    $this->db->join("ospos_sales os", "os.sale_id = osp.sale_id", "inner");
    $this->db->join("ospos_sales_items i", "os.sale_id = osp.sale_id","INNER");
    $this->db->where('osp.payment_type', 'Cheque');
    $this->db->where('os.sale_status', 0);
    $this->db->like('osp.payment_time', $date);
    $this->db->group_by('i.sale_id');
    return $this->db->get()->row('payment');

}
```

**From above I join to table to get the result works fine, the problem I want to join another table so I can add stock location id, but where I join it return wrong results due to this table have the relationship of multiple ids.**

```
function getTotalCheque_per_dayGeneral($date,$stock_location)
{
    $this->db->select_sum('(osp.`payment_amount`)', 'payment' );
    $this->db->from("ospos_sales_payments as osp");
    $this->db->join("ospos_sales os", "os.sale_id = osp.sale_id", "inner");
    $this->db->join("ospos_sales_items i", "os.sale_id = osp.sale_id","INNER");
    $this->db->where('osp.payment_type', 'Cheque');
    $this->db->where('os.sale_status', 0);
    $this->db->where('i.item_location = ', $stock_location);
    $this->db->like('osp.payment_time', $date);
    $this->db->group_by('i.sale_id');
    return $this->db->get()->row('payment');
     
        //print_r($this->db->last_query());

}
```

[image: ospos_sales]

[image: ospos_sales_items]

[image: ospos_sales_payments]

*In short I try to get payment amount by filter date and stock location in payment type credit Card*

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: I cannot test this, as you don't provide a simple SQL sample, see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), anyway, I'd suggest to put the new where inside the join like: `$this->db->join("ospos_sales_items i", "os.sale_id = osp.sale_id and i.item_location =  $stock_location","INNER");` , remove corresponding WHERE: `$this->db->where('i.item_location = ', $stock_location);`which has a typo btw `',